Work item created subscription in Azure ADO triggers notification for updates too
Created a subscription in Azure Dev Ops to receive a notification when a work item is created. I receive a notification when a work item meets the filter criteria as expected, but ADO sends me notifications for all subsequent updates too. How to restrict notification only for item creation?
Filter configuration:
State Changes from--> Blank
And Authorizes As <> [Member]
And Work item type = Bug
And Environment_ACN=Production

Hi @KiranRam, Welcome to SO. Have you got a chance to the notification email following the suggestion in my answer below? Hope it can help resolve your query in this post. Thx for the sharing.

You may check in your personal Notifications settings if your user account has subscribed/enabled other notifications that could have sent emails to you upon work items updates. For example, as defined in the global notification of A work item assigned, it will send emails to a list of users.

You may also double check your team/group custom subscription, if the settings in the screenshot below are defined as expected.

And you could tell from the subscriptionId if the email was sent by the subscription that you mentioned.

